# How can I access an Outlook 2003 PST file without using Outlook?

Tags: pst

I have a 450MB PST file (Outlook 2003 backup file) saved from a PC before it crashed.

I would like to break it up into its components i.e.

1. Save attachments to folders on my PC
2. Paste text emails into a word processor
3. ... etc.

However I don't want to buy Office Professional 2003 or later solely for importing the PST into Outlook 2003+. Outlook Express cannot import PST files - only Outlook can do this properly.

Is there another way to access the 450MB file?

Answer (score 1):

There are third party tools for opening PST files - however I have not seen any good (free) ones that I could recommend.

Alternatively, you could download [Thunderbird](https://www.mozilla.org/en-GB/thunderbird/) - a free email client by the Mozilla team, which can import PST files.

The best solution is probably to download a [trial of Office](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/try/), then you can use the full Outlook to do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Wil's suggestion is probably the best way to go. However, if you're looking for something more robust for a network environment, "[Kernel for Exchange Server](http://www.kerneldatarecovery.com/exchange-server-recovery.html)" will let you look at .pst files as well as the raw .edb files from an Exchange server. You can browse individual items and export them as well.